# TypeError: Named argument does not match function declaration

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm getting the following error while compiling this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Campaign
{
    struct Request
    {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool compelete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address=>bool) approvals;
    }
    Request[] public requests;
    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    mapping (address=> bool) public approvers;

    modifier restricted()
    {
        require(msg.sender==manager);
        _;
    }
    function Campaign(uint minimum) public
    {
        manager = msg.sender;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }
    function Contribute() public payable
    {
        require(msg.value >= minimumContribution);
        approvers[msg.sender]=true;

    }
    function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted 
    {
        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            description:description,
            value:value,
            recipient:recipient,
            complete:false,
            approvalCount: 0
            });
        requests.push(newRequest);
    }
    function approveRequest(uint index) public {

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!requests[index].approvals[msg.sender]);

        requests[index].approvals[msg.sender]=true;
        requests[index].approvalCount++;
    }
}
```

[image]`

Comment: Typo in the code, that is the reason.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `compelete` in the declaration and `complete` in the initialization!